# How to shift bit 4 bits to the left in y86?

Tags: y86

I am looking to recreate the x86 shl dest,src instruction in y86 assembly language.  Specifically, I need to shift a dest bit 4 bits to the left.  Could anyone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

There are no shifting and multiplying operations in y86. You can shift a value one bit to the left by adding it to itself. Shifting four bits means four additions:

```
addl %eax, %eax
addl %eax, %eax
addl %eax, %eax
addl %eax, %eax
```

Comment: what if there is a need to wrap around?

Comment: @user3487763: Then you would write the value to a memory location and then read it offset by one byte to shift it eight bits to the right. Then you shift it four bits to the left (as above), write it to a memory location and read id offset by three bytes to get it in the lower byte. Do an `and` operation with 0x000f to isolate the four bits. Get the original value and shift it for bits to the left, the do an `or` operation to get the four bits into the value.

Comment: does y86 have a carry flag?

Comment: Isn't it `addq` and `%rax`?

Answer (score 0):

Shift operations are not in the Y86 instruction set. You can emulate shifting 4 bits to the left by multiplying with 2^4 = 16.

Comment: There is no multiplication in the instruction set either.

Comment: ^right...how would you actually implement that? that's what I'm stuck on

Comment: A loop that adds multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what we need to do:

- Build a multiplication routine for positive values, accounting for
  overflow.
- Figure out what sign the result should have.
- Convert the operands to absolute values (using a negation routine.)
- Call the multiplication routine on the absolute values.
- Consider and handle overflow.
- Convert the resulting amount to negative if necessary.

The rest is up to you. By the way… the maximum limit of a signed 32-bit integer value (as designated by a .LONG value) is 231-1 or 2,147,483,647.